# Listing a User's Products by Category in Eloquent

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

[image: Model excerpt]

Basically I have the following tables and I'm trying to list for a given user all his products by category.

Example:

```
{
 user_id: 1
 username: xpto
   categories: [{
      id: 1
      name: category_1
        products: [{
          id: 3
          name: prod1
        },
        {
          id: 3
          name: prod1
        }],
      id: 2
      name: category_2
        products: [{
          id: 6
          name: prod5
        }],
    }]
}
```

The closest I got from my desired result was with this query:
`App\User::with('products.category')->find(1);`

Already spent a lot of hours thinking about this, but no clue, starting to feel desperate. Help please.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Does the query you provided (App\User) return data?

Comment: @Dave it returns data but not the data I want (and in the format i want). So basically i have no clue how to write the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent doesn't use a single query with joins to return data, making it a poor choice when you need to filter related tables.  Your eloquent call:

```
App\User::with('products.category')->find(1);
```

...actually performs several queries.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1

SELECT * FROM products JOIN product_user ... WHERE user_id = 1

SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id IN (...all of the category_ids returned from products...)
```

You should immediately see the problem:  Eloquent first queries all users and stores them in an array, then uses separate queries to fetch products and categories.  Thus you can't sort users by categories.

There are two ways to tackle this:

1. Use Eloquent to fetch users with products and categories (as in the example you provide), then iterate over the results and pull out (and sort) the categories and products.
2. Construct a proper query using joins.

   ```
   User::select('users.name as user_name', 'products.name as product_name', 'categories.name as category_name')
           ->join('product_user', 'users.id', '=', 'product_user.user_id')
           ->join('products', 'product_user.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
           ->join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
           ->orderBy('categories.name')
           ->get();
   ```

Note that you'll need to specify column aliases if your tables share column names like id, name, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Will work on you example to get what I'm looking for (pretty close tho) :)